# How can I split a line that contains an underline with awk?

Tags: linux, awk, output, line

I have this line, but I want each part of it separated and I want this separation to be done with awk.

The original line is the following:

```
3302491505_8139829707_13970101.csv
```

and what I want as an output is:

```
8139829707
```

or this:

```
3302491505
```

Comment: Is this what you want: `awk -F_ '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i+0}' <<<"3302491505_8139829707_13970101.csv"`  ?

Comment: no I want print just one of them: 8139829707 or 3302491505

Comment: what is the problem of printing the 1st field using `_` as field separator? Make some effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with cut:

```
$ cut -d_ -f2 <<< "3302491505_8139829707_13970101.csv" 
8139829707
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -F'[_.]' '{print $2; print $1}'  <<< "3302491505_8139829707_13970101.csv"
```

`-F` sets the field separator to `_` or `.`. It allows to set the fields `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: this prints the whole line

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -n "3302491505_8139829707_13970101.csv" | awk -F'[._]' '{print $1}'
```

THis seperates by `_` or `.` and then print whichever field you need
Just print

- `$1` for first field : 3302491505
- `$2` for 2nd field : 8139829707
- `$3` for 3rd field : 13970101

Answer (score 0):

This prints all parts individually

```
$ awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1; print $2; print $3; print $4}'  <<< "3302491505_8139829707_13970101.csv"
3302491505
8139829707
13970101
csv
```

Just use the field you want.

```
$ awk -F'[_.]' '{ print $3;}'  <<< "3302491505_8139829707_13970101.csv"
13970101
```

Answer (score 0):

Bourne-like shells have a built-in way to split strings. That's what happens when you leave a parameter expansion unquoted and the source of so many bug when you don't want that to happen.

So it would seem only fair to use it when it's actually needed.

```
IFS=_ # split on _
set -o noglob # leaving a parameter expansion unquoted also
              # involves filename generation which we don't want here

var=3302491505_8139829707_13970101.csv
set -- $var # $var unquoted means its split

printf '%s: %s\n' First "$1" Second "$2" Third "$3"
```

Some shells have less cumbersome ways to split strings.

In `zsh`:

```
var=3302491505_8139829707_13970101.csv
non_empty_parts=(${(s:_:)var})
parts=("${(@s:_:)var}")
```

Or directly:

```
printf '%s\n' "Second part: ${${(s:_:)var}[2]}"
```